Powershell WSUS missing patch script not working
Script does not seem to pull the systems from any the Workstation Patching Groups
but if i change them to the server groups  Server Patching Group it works
I was wondering if it the way someone named the groups is the - causing the problem i just get a empty report
Works
Server Patching Group 1
Empty report
Workstation Patching - Group 1
#Load WSUS Assemblies
[void][system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration')

#Functions for AD
function Get-ADObject([string]$samid,[string]$objectClass){
     $searcher=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
     $searcher.Filter="(&(objectclass=$objectClass)(sAMAccountname=$samid))"
     $user=$searcher.FindOne()
      if ($user -ne $null ){
          $user.getdirectoryentry()
     }
}

#Variables 
$WSUSServer = "WSUS.local.com"

#Connect To WSUS Server 
$Global:wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($WSUSServer,$False,8530)

#Set Computer Scope
$ComputerScope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope

#Set Update Scope
$UpdateScope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$UpdateScope.IncludedInstallationStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateInstallationStates] "Downloaded,Failed,NotInstalled,InstalledPendingReboot"
$UpdateScope.ApprovedStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ApprovedStates] "LatestRevisionApproved"

#Retrieve All Servers
$ServersID = @($wsus.GetComputerTargets($ComputerScope))

$Servers = @()

$ServersID | % { 

$ServerInfo = "" | Select ComputerName,Description,ServerGroup,Needed,Failed,InstalledPendingReboot



$ServerInfo.ComputerName = $_.FullDomainName
#Get AD Object and Retrieve Computer Name
$CompShortName = $_.FullDomainname -replace '\..+'
$CompShortName += "$"
$objComputer = Get-ADObject $CompShortName "Computer"
If ($objComputer) {$ServerInfo.Description = $objComputer.Get("Description")}
Else { $ServerInfo.Description = "NO AD Info" }
$ServerInfo.ServerGroup = $_.RequestedTargetGroupName
$UpdateInfo = $_.GetUpdateInstallationInfoPerUpdate($UpdateScope)
$ServerInfo.Needed = ($UpdateInfo | ? { $_.UpdateApprovalAction -eq "Install" -and $_.UpdateInstallationState -ne "Failed" -and $_.UpdateInstallationState -ne "InstalledPendingReboot" }).Count
$ServerInfo.Failed = ($UpdateInfo | ? { $_.UpdateApprovalAction -eq "Install" -and $_.UpdateInstallationState -eq "Failed" }).Count
$ServerInfo.InstalledPendingReboot = ($UpdateInfo | ? { $_.UpdateApprovalAction -eq "Install" -and $_.UpdateInstallationState -eq "InstalledPendingReboot" }).Count

$Servers += $ServerInfo

}

#Adding Styling to HTML
$htmlhead = @"
<title>Patching Compliance Report for WSUS Server:$WSUSServer</title>
<style>
h1 {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table.summary,tr.summary,td.summary {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: left;
    background: transparent;
}


table {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #000;
  background: #bcd0e4 ;
}

caption
{
  caption-side: bottom;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}

th,td
{
  border: 1px dotted #666;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}

th[scope=col]
{
  color: #000;
  background-color: #8fadcc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-right: 2px solid #333;
}

th+th[scope=col]
{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7d98b3;
  border-right: 1px dotted #666;
}

th[scope=row]
{
  background-color: #b8cfe5;
  border-right: 2px solid #333;
}

tr.alt th, tr.alt td
{
  color: #2a4763;
}

tr:hover th[scope=row],tr:hover td
{
  background-color: #271668;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
"@

#Output To HTML
#List of Patch Group
$NeedUpdates = $Servers | ? {$_.Needed -gt 0 -or $_.Failed -gt 0 -or $_.InstalledPendingReboot -gt 0 } | Sort ComputerName
$WebServers = $NeedUpdates | ? { $_.ServerGroup -eq "Workstation Patching - Group 1"}
$CorpServers = $NeedUpdates | ? { $_.ServerGroup -eq "Workstation Patching - Group 2" }
$CorpServer2 = $NeedUpdates | ? { $_.ServerGroup -eq "Workstation Patching - Special" }

#Pulling Data for Web Servers
$WebNeeded = $WebServers | Measure-Object Needed -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$WebFailed = $WebServers | Measure-Object Failed -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$WebInstalledPendingReboot = $WebServers | Measure-Object InstalledPendingReboot -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$SummaryWeb = "" | Select ComputerName,Description,ServerGroup,Needed,Failed,InstalledPendingReboot
$SummaryWeb.ComputerName = "Total"
$SummaryWeb.Description = "Total for All"
$SummaryWeb.Needed = $WebNeeded
$SummaryWeb.Failed = $WebFailed
$SummaryWeb.InstalledPendingReboot = $WebInstalledPendingReboot

#Pulling Data for  Servers
$CorpNeeded = $CorpServers | Measure-Object Needed -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$CorpFailed = $CorpServers | Measure-Object Failed -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$CorpInstalledPendingReboot = $CorpServers | Measure-Object InstalledPendingReboot -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$SummaryCorp = "" | Select ComputerName,Description,ServerGroup,Needed,Failed,InstalledPendingReboot
$SummaryCorp.ComputerName = "Total"
$SummaryCorp.Description = "Total for All"
$SummaryCorp.Needed = $CorpNeeded
$SummaryCorp.Failed = $CorpFailed
$SummaryCorp.InstalledPendingReboot = $CorpInstalledPendingReboot

#Pulling Data for Servers_Manual
$CorpNeeded2 = $CorpServer2 | Measure-Object Needed -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$CorpFailed2 = $CorpServer2 | Measure-Object Failed -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$CorpInstalledPendingReboot2 = $CorpServer2 | Measure-Object InstalledPendingReboot -Sum | % {$_.Sum}
$SummaryCorp2 = "" | Select ComputerName,Description,ServerGroup,Needed,Failed,InstalledPendingReboot
$SummaryCorp2.ComputerName = "Total"
$SummaryCorp2.Description = "Total for All"
$SummaryCorp2.Needed = $CorpNeeded2
$SummaryCorp2.Failed = $CorpFailed2
$SummaryCorp2.InstalledPendingReboot = $CorpInstalledPendingReboot2

#Pulling the Count of servers missing or faled patches
$CorpCount = $CorpServers.Count
$WebCount = $WebServers.Count
$CorpCount2 = $CorpServer2.Count
$TotalCount = $CorpCount + $WebCount + $CorpCount2

$WebServers += $SummaryWeb
$CorpServer += $SummaryCorp
$CorpServer2 += $SummaryCorp2

$MainBody = @"
<h1>Patching Compliance Report</h1>
<h2>Total Workstation - $TotalCount</h2>
"@

$WebBody = @"
<table class="summary">
<tr class="summary">
    <td class="summary"><b>Group:</b></td>
    <td class="summary">Workstation Patching - Group 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="summary">
    <td class="summary"><b>Total Workstation:</b></td>
    <td class="summary">$WebCount</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
"@

$CorpBody = @"
<table class="summary">
<tr class="summary">
    <td class="summary"><b>Group:</b></td>
    <td class="summary">Workstation Patching - Group 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="summary">
    <td class="summary"><b>Total Workstation:<b></td>
    <td class="summary">$CorpCount</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
"@

$CorpBody2 = @"
<table class="summary">
<tr class="summary">
    <td class="summary"><b>Group:</b></td>
    <td class="summary">Workstation Patching - Special</td>
</tr>
<tr class="summary">
    <td class="summary"><b>Total Workstation:<b></td>
    <td class="summary">$CorpCount2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
"@

$WebHtml = $WebServers | ConvertTo-Html -head $htmlhead -body $WebBody
$CorpHtml = $CorpServers | ConvertTo-Html -head $htmlhead -body $CorpBody
$Corp2Html = $CorpServer2 | ConvertTo-Html -head $htmlhead -body $CorpBody2



$OutPut = $MainBody + $WebHtml + "<br><br>" + $CorpHtml  +"<br><br>" +  $Corp2Html

Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml $OutPut -From "e-mail@local.com" -SmtpServer "test" -Subject "Workstation Patch Compliancy Report" -To "e-mail@local.com"

#Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml $OutPut -From "" -SmtpServer "" -Subject "Server Patch Compliancy Report" -To "

#Invoke-Expression C:\Reports\Test.htm

a HTML report sent to a e-mail list, i have removed e-mail address and the servers from the script

If it were me I'd run everything up to #List of Path Group, then do $Servers | Group ServerGroup | Select Name and see if the names it outputs matches the names you have in the next few lines. Could it be a fancy dash character instead of a hyphen? Maybe there's an extra space in there you weren't expecting? Or try filtering with a regex match like ? { $_.ServerGroup -match 'Workstation Pa.+Group 1' } and see if that works better for you. My suspicion is that there's a slight mismatch between the actual group name and what you typed.

Sorry for the long delay been one fire after another at work, It works better but i still do not get a full list report show 14 PC missing updates and WSUS show 102
